# blurred images using load()

Tags: image, textures, godot, gdscript

I'm loading my images using `load()` like this:

```
get_node("%CustomSprite").texture=load(img_path)
```

but they're being loaded in blurry, I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvXaHQbkzxI) video to fix it,

so is there any way to reimport images via gdscript?
or any work around to make the image sharp?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'll point out that if you are using `load`, that texture is already imported.

Now, let us see. I'll give you three solutions, from more to less involved. *All tested in Godot 3.5.*

---

### Re-import the texture

If you are writing an `EditorPlugin`, re-import makes some sense. Sadly, I'm not aware of a direct way to do it.

Instead, you can open the file with `.import` extension that Godot creates for the asset (it contains the import configuration) with `ConfigFile` (it is basically an INI file).

```
var config := ConfigFile.new()
config.load(img_path + ".import")
```

In the `.import` file you can find what are the imported resources (I mean, the resource files in Godot binary format which are located in the `.import` folder). To get the list, read the `"dest_files"` of the `"deps"` section.

```
var dest_files:Array = config.get_value("deps", "dest_files")
```

Since you want to force a re-import you can delete them:

```
var dir := Directory.new()
for dest_file in dest_files:
    dir.remove(dest_file)
```

Or move them to trash:

```
for dest_file in dest_files:
    OS.move_to_trash(ProjectSettings.globalize_path(dest_file))
```

Now, you want to change the settings so they are not blurry. I believe, in particular you want to set the value `"flags/filter"` of the `"params"` section to `false`.

```
config.set_value("params", "flags/filter", false)
```

Ah, you need to save it!

```
config.save(img_path + ".import")
```

And now tell Godot to re-scan the files calling `scan` from the `EditorFileSystem` class (you get an instance calling `get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem()` from your `EditorPlugin`).

```
get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem().scan()
```

It should re-import resource (generate again the files in the `".import"` folder).

Before you load the resource again, know that scanning the file system is not synchronous. So you want to yield on it.

```
yield(get_editor_interface().get_resource_filesystem(), "filesystem_changed")
```

One more thing. Even though you are re-importing the resource. It might be in cache. So, load it with `ResourceLoader.load` and specify to bypass the cache:

```
var my_texture = ResourceLoader.load(img_path, "", true)
```

---

### Creating a texture form an image file

Please notice that re-importing a resource modifies the project.

If you have an image file and want a texture from it, you can read the image file and skip the whole resource import system.

Let us read the contents of the image file:

```
var file := File.new()
file.open(img_path, File.READ)
var buffer := file.get_buffer(file.get_len())
file.close()
```

And now, let us create an `Image` object from that (I'm assuming it is a png):

```
var my_image := Image.new()
my_image.load_png_from_buffer(buffer)
```

And now a texture from it:

```
var my_texture := ImageTexture.new()
my_texture.create_from_image(my_image)
```

About making sure it is not blurry, you want to set the `flags` property. In particular remove `FLAG_FILTER`.

---

If you are working with `VisualServer`, you might want to use `texture_create_from_image` instead:

```
var texture_rid := VisualServer.texture_create_from_image(my_image)
```

And for the flags, you can use `VisualServer.texture_set_flags`. Again, remove `FLAG_FILTER` to make it not blurry.

---

### Just change texture flags

So, at the end you need to make sure `FLAG_FILTER` is not set. I believe you should be able to modify it after loading:

```
var my_texture = load(img_path)
my_texture.flags = 0
```